# How to get statistic from array in a Spark dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with a dataframe

```
    df.printSchema()
     root
       |-- key_value: struct (nullable = true)
       |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
       |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
    df.show(5)
    |key_value
    |[k1,v1]
    |[k1,v2]
    |[k2,v3
    |[k3,v6]
    |[k4,v5]
```

I want to get the number of distinct keys in My dataframe, so I try to construct a dataframe that contains a column key and value using explode but I didn't get a result.

```
   val f=df.withColumn("k",explode(col("key_value")))
   org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'explode(`key_value`)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not StructType(StructField(key,StringType,true), StructField(value,StringType,true));;
```

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this

```
import spark.implicits._    
df.select($"key_value.key").distinct.count
```

the `explode` function is applied on array fields, in this case neither `key_value` or `key` are an array.